# Is there a simpler way to make an English-readable list from strings in a tuple?

Tags: python, strings

I looking over some old code, I had written the function below with a C-style for-loop iterating over a count variable. I then fixed it up with new knowledge, but still am suspicious that there is even a better way to do this.

The function should behave like so:

```
>>> join_list(['a'])
'a'
>>> join_list(['a', 'b'])
'a or b'
>>> join_list(['a', 'b', 'c'])
'a, b, or c'
```

The function I have currently:

```
def join_list(my_list):
    length = len(my_list)
    if length == 1:
        return my_list[0]
    elif length == 2:
        return ' or '.join(my_list)
    else:
        head = ', '.join(my_list[:-1])
        return head + ', or ' + my_list[-1]
```

Comment: There's no docstring!

Comment: To be fair I defined this function within my `if __name__ == '__main__'` conditional, but I digress I think the code speaks for itself :).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks pretty good. The only problem I can see is that you're not doing a check to make sure the list is not empty: if it is, then you'll try to access `my_list[-1]` in the final `else` clause, which will raise an `IndexError`.

Hence, I'd simply add a check up front for `length == 0` and `return ''` in that case.

Comment: if you handle 2 and 3 item cases first you can fall through to `''.join(my_list)` which covers both 0 and 1

Comment: I like that a lot, but I want to test for least first. All I need to change is the first clause to `if length <= 1: ''.join(my_list)`

Answer (score 2):

You could also write, a bit shorter:

```
def join_list(items):
    if not items:
        return ''
    *init, last = map(str, items)
    return (', '.join(init) + ' or '*bool(init) + last)
```

Example:

```
>>> join_list(range(5))
'0, 1, 2, 3 or 4'
```

Comment: I tested that on Python 2.7.6 and Python 3.3. Looks like the asterisk in `*init, last = map(str, items)` raises a `SyntaxError` on Python 2.7.6. Do you know what that feature of Python 3.3 is called?

Comment: @Winny Sorry, forgot to mention its python3 code. Its called extended unpacking (pep 3132).